# Prove $ x \cdot \int \limits_0^x f(t)dt \geqslant \int \limits_0^x t \cdot f(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Prove that $ x \cdot \int \limits_0^x f(t)dt \geqslant  \int \limits_0^x t \cdot f(t)dt$, where $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(x) \geqslant 0 \ \forall x \geqslant 0$.

I know that it can be done using integration by parts, but it's quite inconvenient.

I think another option it is to think about this inequality in terms of area, but I can't put my thoughts accurately.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)>0$...?

Comment: Is the inequality strict?

Comment: We have equality if $x = 0$ or if $f(x) = 0$ on $[0,x]$.

Comment: What are you allowed to know? Can you use the positivity of the integral? ... with $f(t) > 0$ for $t \geq 0$, then $x f(t) > t f(t)$ for $0 \leq t < x$ ...

Comment: @Tom You meant the monotonicity of the integral? If $f(x) \geqslant g(x)\ \forall x \Rightarrow \int f(x) \geqslant \int g(x) \ \forall x$.

Comment: @NegligibleSenescence Monotonicity is equivalent to positivity, where positivity is defined as $f \geq 0 \implies \int f \geq 0$. In your example, just consider $h = f - g$ and use the linearity of the integral to conclude monotonicity.

Comment: Just a thought, might not be rigorous. If we can interpret $$p(t) \equiv \frac{f(t)}{\int_0^x f(t') \, dt'}$$ as a probability density function over [0, x], then the inequality to prove means $x \geqslant \int_0^x t \, p(t) \, dt = \overline{t}$, which is self-evident: the average over a domain is no greater than the upper bound of the domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f(t)\geq0$ for $x\geq0$ then obviously
$$\int_0^x(x-t)f(t)\>dt\geq0 \qquad(x\geq0)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

An obvious generalization is
$g(x)\int \limits_0^x f(t)dt \ge  \int \limits_0^x g(t)f(t)dt
$
if
$f(x) \ge 0$,
$g(x) \ge 0$
and
$g'(x) \ge 0$.

Your case is
$g(x) = x$.

For a proof,
since
$g'(t) \ge 0$,
if $x \ge t$ then
by the MVT,
$g(x)- g(t)
=(x-t)g'(z)
$
where
$t \le z \le t$
so that
$g(x) \ge g(t)$.
Therefore
$\int \limits_0^x (g(x)-g(t))f(t)dt
\ge 0
$.